# I'm using two different jQuery functions and one seems to be canceling the other out

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I'm using two different jQuery functions and one seems to be canceling the other out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528161/im-using-two-different-jquery-functions-and-one-seems-to-be-canceling-the-other)

I had the following script set up for a lightbox:

and when I added the following code for a smooth scrolling effect (I'm building a single page, scrolling website), the previously working lightbox was rendered ineffective.



They both work just fine on their own, but when I use them both, the lightbox no longer works.

Comment: Where is the code? It doesn't look like it came through.

Comment: Please edit properly your question